# Initiating a popover button script

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying for a while now to get this popover working on my project. Bare in mind a couple of things:

- I really don't have any experience with CSS or JS functions
- My `head` & `footer` sections are situated in `include` files
- CSS & JS files are located in a folder named `assets`

That being said, here is my `button`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" 
id="test" name="test" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" 
data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
```

And Bootstrap provides a JS code to initiate the popover function:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#test').popover(options);
});
```

Although I've tried many different options with no success. I have attempted to add the JS script to my files under different names and placed it in the `head` area too. I've also tried using `divs` with no avail. If anybody might be able to help out here and maybe provide a brief explanation as to what I've done wrong would be amazing.

Comment: You don't have id attribute for your button. Add `id="button_id"` to the button, In javascript write: `$('#button_id').popover(options);`

Comment: I have added the id section but still nothing, the button clicks but is not showing any popover?

Comment: Did you load jquery?

Comment: I'm assuming so, I've used JS on this project before and it has worked. But this just seems to not be wanting to do anything lol!

Comment: Can you  create a minimal working example on https://jsfiddle.net/, so everybody could reproduce your problem?

Comment: Look in the console. What error does it gives in console? Also `$('#test').popover(options);` should be in the `document.ready` function

Comment: try removing `data-container="body" ` and check

Comment: I've updated to include the `document.ready` function and taken out `data_container="body"` but still not having any change. I'd love to create a jsfiddle.net example, but I wouldn't know what requires including, and where can I find an error in the console?

Comment: Use Inspect element and Check for console tab. Then click on the button to trigger popup. An error will be recorded in the console. Paste that error here.

Comment: Here's a working example of popover. Check waht you have missed.
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=popovers-placement-via-data-attributes

Comment: It seems like I've got it working, just about. By adding `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` script links to the `header` as instructed and also adding this script: `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>` BELOW the button. Thanks for your help with this everybody!

Comment: Ok. I would be posting it as an answer. You can accept it so that future visitors of the post can find the solution easily.

Comment: I'd feel really bad answering my own question as all of you pointed me in the right direction to finding the solution... lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of popover. Check waht you have missed.

[POPOVER EXAMPLE LINK](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=popovers-placement-via-data-attributes)

**SOLUTION as observed by OP:**

Include `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`

Then, Add

`<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); }); </script>`